# How to create a dtd rule for this XML?

Tags: xml, dtd

I need to create a dtd rule for not repeating the values of an XML element, in this case, i have a catalog containing 5 songs (name, artist, album, ...), and the name element values can't be repeated, there can't be two song with the same name, my code here:

```
XML

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
    <song>
    <name>Bed of Roses</name>
    <artist>Bon Jovi</artist>
    <album>Cross Road</album>
    <year>1995</year>
    <genre>Ballad</genre>
    <coments>Good song</coments>
    <path></path>
</song>
<song>
    <name>Fly Away from here</name>
    <artist>Aerosmith</artist>
    <album>Just Push Play</album>
    <year>2001</year>
    <genre>Rock</genre>
    <coments>Good song</coments>
    <path></path>
</song>
</catalog>

DTD
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!ELEMENT catalog (song)>
<!ELEMENT song (name,artist,album,year,genre,comments,path)>
<!ELEMENT song (name)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT artist (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT album (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT genre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT comments (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: This is not possible. DTDs cannot express the kind of constraint you require (ensuring unique values for certain elements). You'll have to use some other technology, for example [Schematron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron).

Comment: My Web teacher is asking me to do that

Comment: @mzjn - It is technically possible (see ugly hack below), but I agree that there are better technologies for ensuring this type of constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you *could* do is use a unique ID on the `name` element. This only gets you half way there though; the ID has to be unique but it doesn't restrict the PCDATA in the `name`.

To get around this, create text entities to hold the name elements. You can only reference the entity once. If you reference it more than once, you'll get an error similar to:

> Attribute value "song1" of type ID must be unique within the document.

This will ensure that the name only gets used once.

Here's an example. (You also had some typos that made your XML/DTD invalid. Those have been fixed.)

**catalog.dtd**

```
<!ELEMENT catalog (song+)>
<!ELEMENT song (name,artist,album,year,genre,comments,path)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST name
          id ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT artist (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT album (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT genre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT comments (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT path (#PCDATA)>

<!ENTITY song1 '<name id="song1">Bed of Roses</name>'>
<!ENTITY song2 '<name id="song2">Fly Away from here</name>'>
```

**XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
    <song>
        &song1;
        <artist>Bon Jovi</artist>
        <album>Cross Road</album>
        <year>1995</year>
        <genre>Ballad</genre>
        <comments>Good song</comments>
        <path></path>
    </song>
    <song>
        &song2;
        <artist>Aerosmith</artist>
        <album>Just Push Play</album>
        <year>2001</year>
        <genre>Rock</genre>
        <comments>Good song</comments>
        <path></path>
    </song>
</catalog>
```

Disclaimer: I think this is an ugly hack personally. Like mzjn said in the comments, there are other technologies better suited to ensuring this type of constraint.

Comment: Making use of the uniqueness of IDs works, but this does not restrict the element content. Having "Bed of Roses" as the name of both songs does not result in an error. Ugly hack indeed. But creative. Worth an upvote.